# join two files on first two columns and print columns from files

Tags: bash, unix, join, awk, merge

if I have the following:

file 1

```
1 a qpqp
2 b qpqp
3 c qpqp
```

file 2

```
1 a xkcd
2 b xkcd
3 d xkcd
```

I want to join both files where columns 1 and 2 match, and print the output side by side. i.e.

```
1 a qpqp 1 a xkcd
2 b qpqp 2 b xkcd
```

I can print just the first file columns using

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

But as I mentioned, I want to print the columns from both tables. Thanks!

`extra info`- the files will not be sorted beforehand (takes too long), and file 2 is MUCH bigger than file 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1 FS $2]=$0;next} (($1 FS $2) in a) {print a[$1 FS $2],$0}' file1 file2
1 a qpqp 1 a xkcd
2 b qpqp 2 b xkcd
```